# Can I say that this matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{x_1^3x_2}&\frac{1}{x_1^2x_2^2}\\\frac{1}{x_1^2x_2^2}&\frac{2}{x_1 x_2^3}\end{bmatrix}

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive real numbers.

Using Slyvester's Citerion:

$\frac{2}{x_2 x_1^3} > 0$

$\frac{2}{x_2 x_1^3}\frac{2}{x_1 x_2^3}-\frac{1}{x_1^2x_2^2}\frac{1}{x_1^2x_2^2} > 0$

The solution claims that this matrix is positive semi definite, but I don't see a way for the principle minors to be 0.

Comment: It's a 2x2...a symmetric (real) 2x2 is positive definite if $T>0$ and $\Delta>0$, as you can see directly from the formula for the eigenvalues. Sylvester's criterion is more or less equivalent.

Comment: What is T and $\Delta$?

Comment: $T=$Trace and $\Delta=$determinant.

Comment: You're likely missing a square in the lower left corner of your matrix.  What you wrote is not symmetric.

Comment: Whoops yeah you're right.

Comment: Also would this still be true for a 3x3 symmetric matrix? That if $T>0$  and $\Delta>0$, then it's positive definite?

Comment: @dinoblue No, in the 3x3 case you can have eigenvalues like $10,-1,-2$ in which case $T>0$ and $\Delta>0$ but it isn't positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is $\frac3{x_1^4x_2^4}\neq 0$ so it can't have a $0$ eigenvalue. However it still is positive semi-definite (as well as positive definite)